Audit attempts to access the Database, only failed for some users and all attempts for the rest
I am needing help to be able to configure an audit mechanism that allows me to record in the audit_trail the login (or create session) attempts in my databases, the problem comes when I need to record all access attempts whether successful or not, except , the application users who only need to be registered in case of failed attempts.
For example, I have user1, user2, user3, user_app1, user_app2.
I need to audit successful and failed accesses of user1, user2, user3.
I need to audit only failed attempts from user_app1 and user_app2.
My parameter audit_trail=DB
They are Oracle 19c Databases
Could you help me from your experience?

What is the reason for not capturing successful logins for all users? Most cyber security policies would require that.
